# PLC output optoisolation with mosfet output

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator, plc

I'm wondering if this circuit i've made is correct.
Basically i want to separate PLC transistor outputs from loads.
I need 500mA output current for LEDs but also for relays etc.
PLC and loads are supplied by diferent power supplies - PLC from INT24, loads from EXT24. DO1+ is PLC NPN output.
Also i've add TVS and revers polarity protection.

Please give me advice if there is something which i can do better.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Fault: Vgs of Q1 not regarded, it will blow. How does "EARTH" relate to "EXT24-"? Why do you need reverse polarity protection? What should it protect, and from what influence?

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about it. Now i have 12V zener,but will mosfet turn off properly? Add ex.10k resistor between G-S to discharge gate? I've removed D1 cause it's not needed there,right? Also I've replaced the DS cause you made me realize that reverse polarity protection mosfet is in "wrong direction". RPP will avoid passing all current over flywheel diode if someone connect power wrong all. Earth is ground.Sorry for my english. It's connected to fifth wire of power cable (L1,L2,L3,N,PE). Are you sugessting to connect TVS between signal and EXT24-?
![sch][https://i.imgur.com/cTDOMTq.png]

Comment: Please edit your question an include the new schematic there.

Comment: Edited with new schematic. Sorry, i'm new here.

Comment: You are welcome! It remains unclear for what reason you put your "reverse polarity protection"  on the negative side of EXT24. What do you think does it protect?